# Permanently Delete File C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having a simple problem that I cannot find a simple solution to. I am trying to delete a file permanently. I'm not looking for the fanciest way to make the data unrecoverable, I just don't want it sitting in the Recycle Bin. I have two questions.

1. Is the a way to get the path to the Recycle Bin? The idea is that once I have the path I can use `remove()` to delete it permanently from there. The following fails for me, returning a completely different path that isn't that of the Recycle Bin. Maybe I am missing an argument.

   ```
   char RecycleBin[_MAX_PATH];   
   SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, RecycleBin, CSIDL_BITBUCKET, FALSE);
   ```
2. Is there a win32api call to permanently delete a file?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT 1:

Per the answer below, I have been using the `_unlink ()` function but it's behavior doesn't do exactly what I want it to do. I need something to get the Desktop, then add a file to that string and pass the string into a function that will delete the file as an argument. Here is how I am trying with unlink.If I do unlink like this - it works:

```
     char path [] = "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Desktop\\test.dat";

     _unlink( path );
```

However, if I try it in the two following ways it fails.

```
    char DesktopPath[_MAX_PATH];

    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, DesktopPath, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);

    strcat ( DesktopPath, "\\test.dat" );

    _unlink ( DesktopPath );
```

This way (adding quotes) also fails.

```
    char DesktopPath[_MAX_PATH];

    char final_path [] = "\"";

    char quotes [] = "\"";

    SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, DesktopPath, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, FALSE);

    strcat ( DesktopPath, "\\test.dat" );

    strcat ( DesktopPath, quotes );

    strcat ( final_path, DesktopPath );

    _unlink ( final_path );
```

Both of the above ways compile and run fine, but it doesn't actually get rid of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you want [DeleteFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you need to remove a file directly, without first sending it to the Recycle Bin, or do you need to remove a file that's already in the Recycle Bin?

Comment: @Keith, Either would work. Do you know how I can get the path to the Recycling Bin?

Comment: @Jorge: No idea -- but the `remove()` function should delete the file without going through the Recycle Bin.

Comment: `remove ()` puts it in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Jorge: Are you sure? It's [not documented as doing so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2da4hk1d.aspx). It normally requires explicit code to move something to the recycle bin (calling the shell functions) rather than just deleting it.

Comment: @Deanna. I'll try again to verify, but `remove ()` was just putting it into the Recycle Bin before. Could be a permissions error as I'm trying this on Win7?

Comment: @Jorge: Or a 3rd party app trying to be clever?

Comment: I tried it again and you were correct Deanna, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the POSIX function [unlink (_unlink for MSVC2005+)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c3tczd6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
_unlink("file.ext"); //delete file without sending to Recycle Bin
```

Comment: The actual POSIX function is named `unlink`. The C standard library provides an equivalent (but portable) `remove`.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin MS has deprecated unlink and replaced it with _unlink.  His question is for windows and tagged winapi.  But you are correct.